# What is the easiest way to determine all forks are done in Python

Tags: python, gcloud

Sorry for the butchered title.  I did not have enough space to ask the following question:  Suppose you run a python program and fork the process using `os.fork()`.  When you fork the process it's not very easy to determine when all the forks have been completed.  I need to able to convey to the computer that all forks have been completed because I need to shut the computer down with `sudo shutdown -h now`.  This is because I will be using gcloud which costs $5 an hour.  If the process completes while I'm asleep I don't want to waste $35.

I tried using a global variable where after each fork was done, python would write down in a dictionary that that fork was in fact done.  Even though the variable was a global I still could not get the values of that variable to be the same for each fork.  So I think using global variables is out.  My current work around that I am now thinking about is periodically reading the output of the top command in terminal.  After a fork is completed the process should terminate and no longer show up in the top command.  So once there is only one python process running that should signify that all forks are completed.  It should take about 30 minutes to figure out how to do that, so I'd rather not use that method if someone already knows something easier.

I should also note that this will be done using a Google gcloud virtual instance.  So if gcloud already has something set up where it can determine if a fork process has completed then please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using `os.fork`, I believe the best way is to use [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) to trap `SIGCHLD` (the signal sent to the parent process whenever a child process terminates). Increment a counter every time you fork, decrement and check for zero every time you catch `SIGCHLD`. Since the variable is only in the main thread of the parent process, there is no synchronisation problems.

A better way, if it works for you, is to use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module instead of `os.fork`, as it will do a lot of bookkeeping for you (as well as solve a lot of other recurring problems, like interprocess communication).

EDIT: Here's a toy example for the `os.fork` case.

```
import os
import sys
import random
import signal
import time

def do_something(i):
    print(f"Process {i} starting")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 10))
    print(f"Process {i} ending")
    sys.exit()

running = 0

for i in range(10):
    if os.fork():          # in parent fork (we got the child PID)
        running += 1
    else:                  # in child fork (we got zero)
        do_something(i)

def chld_handler(signo, frame):
    global running
    running -= 1
    print(f"A child died. {running} remain.")
    if not running:
        print("All dead. Exiting.")
        sys.exit()

signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, chld_handler)

while True: time.sleep(1) # loop forever
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I can't figure out to do what you're recommending.  Also, I can't use `multiprocessing` because it does not result in an increase in speed whereas forking does.  So when I used the code `pid = os.fork()` what do I do with the pid?

Comment: Hold on, I think I got it.

Comment: What do you mean, `multiprocessing` does not result in increase of speed whereas forking does? `multiprocessing` should do the same thing fork does (if you don't mess up), it just helps you do it safely and easily. Are you confusing `multiprocessing` with `threading`? It is very hard to give specific answers as you posted no [example]. Regarding `pid`, the result of `os.fork` is always zero in child, and non-zero in parent; but you don't need it for anything in this question.

Comment: I'll respond in 90 minutes.  Now on the road.

Comment: Actually, looking at my notes multiprocessing does speed up the program.  However, it looks like it would take 30 minutes to rewrite my program using multiprocessing and I don't need to do that given forking already works.  My new problem is that I cannot check if a process exists.  I kill the program once and I should get an error when I kill it a second time but that's not happening.  But it doesn't really matter that much since I mainly want to run the program on Linux and right now I'm using a Mac.